# Inline-block links larger than image inside

Tags: html, css

I have a collection of images that are wrapped in anchor tags. The anchor tags are set to display inline-block, so they all appear next to each other:

```
<div>        
    <a href="#"><img src="..." /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="..." /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="..." /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="..." /></a>
</div>
```

Here are my styles:

```
div {
    width: 100%;
}

div a {
    width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;    
}

div a img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

The problem is that the height of the anchor link is a few pixels more than the image inside. This causes a whitespace below each link.

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o0b2wnr9/1/

If you use Firebug or another browser tool, you can see that the anchor links are 4px taller than the images inside.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: add `vertical-align` to `div a img` - http://jsfiddle.net/bt8rbf5g/

Comment: Weird, that was it. Thanks Mary